DiD with one treated unit and a substantial number of zeroes in the dataset
This may be a very basic question, but as I have yet to find a solution to it I'll give it a go:
I wish to run a DiD on time series trade data. I have only one unit in my treatment group, which represents export from state A to state B over 100 months. My control group consists of exports from state A to a minimum of 10 other countries in the same time period.
To my understanding, this research design poses at least two challenges:

The presence of a substantial number of zeroes in the dataset.
Possible breach of the homoskedasticity assumption due to the difference in the number of treated vs untreated units.

My question is: Would it be sufficient to run a DiD with a PPML (Poisson pseudo maximum likelihood) to deal with these issues?
Or, would it be better to run a synthetic control, which is suitable for instances with only one treated unit? If the latter option is recommended, would you recommend combining the approach with a PPML in order to deal with the large amount of zeroes in my data?
I am very grateful for any feedback<3
